# how to root android box without internet

Tags: adb, rooting, root-access, recovery-mode

I am trying to root my android box, but one click root apps refuse to connect to the internet, is there a way to root without internet or android recovery (as adb refuses connection and i dont have power buttons), is there any one click root apps that dont need internet or is there a way to enter recovery without adb, physical buttons and root?

device: rk3222x box (V88 pro) android 5.1.1
tried: kingroot, towelroot and oneclick root

Comment: Common one click root apps like Kingo root and similar don't work on recent (last ~4 years or more) devices.

Comment: my device is running android 5.1.1 and is very old

Comment: Please edit your question and name your device, Android version and the on click root tools you have tried.

Comment: these tv boxes shipped rooted

Comment: mine wasnt, someone who owned this before me removed superSU binary

Comment: first figure out which exact box model you have. Scishion V88 plus is Rockchip RK322x but Scishion V88 pro is Amlogic S905X one can't be true